# FCM Topics Max Payload Size

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am integrating firebase messaging in my system, and I am having troubles sending messages.

The documentation says:

> A notification message is the more lightweight option, with a 2KB
>   limit and a predefined set of user-visible keys. Data messages let
>   developers send up to 4KB of custom key-value pairs. Notification
>   messages can contain an optional data payload that is delivered when
>   users tap on the notification.

But I cannot manage in any way to send 4kb of data in my data message.
This is my curl command

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Authorization: key=my_server_key' -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{
    "to": "/topics/my_test_topic",
    "data": {
        "k" : "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"
     }
}' 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'
```

The string has a size of 3098 bytes , the key is just one, so the total size of the message should be <4kb, but this is the payload I am receiving as response

```
{"error":"MessageTooBig"}
```

The only way I can manage to send this message is to use as recipient the device registration id instead of the topic, but I couldn't find anywhere in the documentation something stating that you can send 4k of data only to single devices and not to topics.

Can someone explain me this behaviour please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. Messages sent through topics have it's own payload size limit of 2KB. From the [GCM Docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging) (emphasis mine):

> **The app server sends messages with payloads up to 2KB to the topic**, and GCM handles the message routing and delivers the message reliably to the right devices.

I linked the GCM docs since it is documwnted there, but since FCM is just running GCM as it's core, it's still applicable.

Comment: I totally missed that since I focused on FCM docs. They should definitely write this on FCM docs ! Thanks

Comment: I'll send in a request as soon as I have free time. :) If you feel like this completely answered your question, do mark it as accepted so that your answer would be tagged accordingly.

Comment: @AL. If i have a string payload which is greater than 4kB any suggestion what can be done?

Comment: @AkshayBhat'AB' A string payload > 4kb is too much for a push notification. I suggest sending the notification as a ping to the user that there is data available to download. Or summarize the text.